# Mixin annotation not getting honored when passed as a parameter

Tags: cxf, jackson, jax-rs

I have a third party class SpecialObject as:

```
public class SpecialObject {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private Date date;
    public String getFoo() {return "foo";} //Outlier
    public String getName() { return name;}
    public Integer getId() {return id;}
    public Date getDate() {return date;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}
    public void setDate(Date date) {this.date = date;}
}
```

I wish to only project out name and date properties when serializing it. Using the magic of MixinAnnotation from Jackson, I created a Mixin interface as:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public interface SpecialObjectMixin {
    @JsonProperty
    public String getName();
    @JsonProperty
    public Date getDate();
}
```

In order to facilitate handling of this SpecialObject as parameter, I have also defined a SpecialObjectHandler which implements the fromString() method.

```
@Override
public SpecialObject fromString(String json) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, SpecialObject.class);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to write JSON output",
                exception);
    }
}
```

When the deserializer invokes this method, the objectMapper throws an error as

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "foo" (Class com.kilo.SpecialObject), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2d2217da; line: 1, column: 60] (through reference chain: com.kilo.SpecialObject["foo"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
at com.kilo.SpecialObjectHandler.fromString(SpecialObjectHandler.java:34)
```

My question is that is there a way that I can have the objectMapper (org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper) also honor annotations from the Mixin where I had configured it to only deal with name and date? Feel free to point out something elementary that I may have overlooked. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with configuration. The mixin was only set on the serialization config and not on the deserialization config causing the issue. Setting it on both configs solves the problem.